# Can I assign an ID to a vtkPoint myself?

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I want to create a VTK Unstructured Grid from FE data in Python.

I have the nodes/points and their ID in an np.Array. Can I now write a VTK file with it and keep the ID assigned by the FE model?

I need a VTK point to which I can assign any ID.

Example:

```
points = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
])

ids = np.array([10, 21, 22, 23, 34, 15, 36, 7])
```

Thanks for any help.

When I try to use `vtk.SetPoint` I get the following error: **ValueError: expects 0 <= id && id <GetNumberOfPoints()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `VTK`, id means "the index in the array list". So it always follows the constraint displayed in the error message.

To keep a trace of your initial ids, you can create a `PointData` array:

```py
ugrid.Points = points
ugrid.PointData.append(ids, "originalIds")
```

see some documentation [here](https://www.kitware.com//improved-vtk-numpy-integration/)